# NestJS CSRF for specefic controller route

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, nestjs

I want to use csrf only for a controller not whole of application.

```
@UsePipes(new CsrfPipe())
```

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as csrf from 'csurf';

@Injectable()
export default class CsrfPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (metadata.type == 'body') {
      const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
      csrfProtection(); // what shall I do here ?
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?  'cause I am looking for same thing right now.

Comment: @TBK Actually I've return back to Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    //Apply csrf for specific routes
    consumer.apply(csrf({ cookie: true })).forRoutes(
      { path: 'auth/login', method: RequestMethod.POST },
      {
        path: 'auth/csrf',
        method: RequestMethod.GET,
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).